# Create a List of Custom form Layout to enter details based on the count entered

Tags: android, forms, listview, android-edittext, android-adapter

I am a novice in Android App Development, learning through online materials, I am developing an app in which i'm stuck at one place, I enter the **Number of Participants** in [layout1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOZQi.png) based on the count i want to generate a custom form that i have designed (shown in [layout2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hee9m.png)) to get the input of so many people. I tried using **Array Adapter** and **Inflator** concepts to display the custom layout in a **ListView** but i couldn't do it, or if it could be acheived please help me. My desired output is shown in [layout3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSBBh.png)

After navigating from Layout1 with the **No of Participants** I'm doing this so that i create my desired ouput as attached in Layout3. These are the things i tried but am stuck, please forgive if the code is ameateur and help me find a way to complete this, your help would be appreciated.

**Layout3Activity**

```
 public class Layout3Activity extends Activity{
    // 
    //
    //
ListView listView;
FriendsLayoutAdapter adapter;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout3);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            adapter = new FriendsLayoutAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.layout2);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    //
    //
    //
    //
    }
```

**layout2.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"> <!-- setting layout height to 160dp so that it only fits in the box we have created-->

    <TextView
        android:text="Friend i"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/friendLabel"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Name here..!!"
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Amount Spent..!!"
        android:id="@+id/amountEditText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/amountTextView"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/amountTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/amountTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Amount:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/amountTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/amountTextView" />

    <!--<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amountEditText"
        android:background="@color/jetBlack">
    </View>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout3.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FriendsLayoutAdapter**

```
public class FriendsLayoutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    String[] friends = {"Friend 1", "Friend 2","Friend 3","Friend 4"};

    public FriendsLayoutAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entries_layout,viewGroup,false);

        TextView  friendLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendLabel);
        TextView  name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView  amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
        EditText nameEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        EditText  amountEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);


        return super.getView(i, view, viewGroup);
    }
//
//
//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your adapter, you are displaying 0 elements.

Try this :

```
public class FriendsLayoutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    String[] friends = {"Friend 1", "Friend 2","Friend 3","Friend 4"};

    public FriendsLayoutAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return friends.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return friends[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String value = friends[i];
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entries_layout,viewGroup,false);

        TextView  friendLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendLabel);
        TextView  name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView  amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amountTextView);
        EditText nameEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        EditText  amountEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);

        friendLabel.setText(value);
        return super.getView(i, view, viewGroup);
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't working, i tried, there's **Unfortunaley App has Stopped** coming up on entering that activity. Any other solution.? Please go through the layout1, layout2 and layout3 . I want the adapter to yield a result as mentioned in layout 3